# url completion in cartoDB info windows

Tags: carto, popup, table, url

By far the most of my data is taken up a column of long strings pointing to the source of the data for each point. I need to keep that. However, it would be neat if CartoDB could use this information (i.e. build the URL) without me providing the full URL, only the relevant ending (and save on the size of the table by not repeating the common part as a long string). Is this doable in their info window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the custom HTML editor of the infowindows to build something like:

```
 <div class="cartodb-popup-content">
  <p><a href="http://foo.bar/{{adm0_a3}}"> Go to {{adm0_a3}} </a> </p>
</div>
```

So if you have the endings of the URL stored in some column, you can avoid repeating the fixed part along all the table.

Comment: Thanks, I would love to try this, but I am not sure what is happening to my table. When I deleted the common string, the text file I upload shrank by 10 MB. When I try to change column types, nothing changed: `year` and `decision_date` can be changed easily, `hufvalue` cannot, because *then* I am notified I am still over the limit. Why didn't the extra 10 MB help? The table is at `https://sandorl.cartodb.com/tables/location_of_winners25mb/`

Answer (score 1):

Try running a vacuum full (http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/VACUUM_FULL) in your table. There is an issue calculating the file sizes when an update is done in the table (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cartodb/XANeWhq9IMc/jV7oNfZXmAgJ).

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, is this the response I should expect? `{"time":9.656,"fields":{},"total_rows":null,"rows":[]}`

Comment: OK, I found the way to run queries from the table view, without the API, sorry I overlooked it before. Now I am confident I ran `VACUUM FULL`, but it only saved me 0.1 MB. I deleted an entire column of strings (length: 10 chars), which still only saved me 0.6 MB out of 37 MB. I still don't know where all the space went, which is unfortunate for a service with a freemium model based mainly based on space constraints…

Comment: Hey Laszlo, could you share with me your table (if it is public of course) ?

Comment: How could I do that?